# VBA - Regex - String in a Word

Tags: json, regex, vba, excel

I'm having this type of json response:

> {"success":true,"data":[{"***guid***":10101,"name":"name1","ispool":true,"dateadded":"2018-09-12T10:22:44","status":5,"lastactivity":"2018-09-13T03:15:06","templatechannels":[{"***guid***":10102,"name":"name2","iscampaign":false,,"ispool":true,"dateadded":"2018-09-12T10:22:44","status":5,"lastactivity":"2018-09-13T03:15:06","templatechannels"},{........}]}]}

I want to get all **guid** from this response...

It may have more than 100 records of **guid**. I want to have all of them.

Comment: You need a JSON parser, not regular expressions.

Comment: A quick google of "VBA JSON" found [this library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) which looks pretty easy to use.

Comment: Yeah but this is a string not json in actual.

Comment: That's what JSON usually is, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is regex based reading your string from a cell. If there can also be `guids` which you want then change the pattern passed to `guids?":(\d+[^,])`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String, i As Long, arr()
    s = [A1]

    arr = GetMatches(s, "guid"":(\d+[^,])")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetMatches(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object, s As String, arrMatches(), i As Long

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = sPattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            ReDim arrMatches(0 To matches.Count - 1)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                arrMatches(i) = iMatch.submatches.item(0)
                i = i + 1
            Next iMatch
        Else
            ReDim arrMatches(0)
            arrMatches(0) = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
    GetMatches = arrMatches
End Function
```

---

**Regex:**

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/CIvrGC/1).

```
/
guid":(\d+[^,])
/
gm
```

`guid":` matches the characters `guid":` literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group `(\d+[^,])`

`\d+` matches a `digit (equal to [0-9])`
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Match a single character not present in the list below `[^,]`
`,` matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

I extract the first group submatch.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I need. I really appreciate your efforts. Thanks man.

Comment: how to iterate now ? like I declare string  as Dim ptrn As String... then in the next line am doing this for ptrn = "" + allThings(k) + """:(\d+[^,])""".... It is giving me errors now ?

Comment: and than arr = GetMatches(rsp, ptrn) will be used than for each iteration.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. The regex will examine the string and write all the matches to the immediate window Ctrl + G. You replace [A1] with the source of the string.

Comment: For k = 1 To 40
            If allThings(k) <> "" Then
                Dim rsp As String, ptrn As String, i As Long, arr()
                rsp = hReq.ResponseText
                ptrn = "" + allThings(k) + """:(\d+[^,])"""
                
                arr = GetMatches(rsp, "guid"":(\d+[^,])")
                For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    MsgBox arr(i)
                Next
            End If
        Next

Comment: It will print all matches in rsp that match the pattern "guid"":(\d+[^,])"  - group1.

Comment: Means I want to iterate like "guid" than "name" than "ispool". Foreach key in loop.

Comment: You have to change the regex because the current regex is to find numbers not letters.

Comment: You want a regex that ends at the next "," I am just gonna eat but will give you something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347964/vba-iterate-through-regex-foreach-key

Answer (score 0):

if you have that string, say, in excel cell A1 you could use this:

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim iArr As Long

arr = Split(Range("A1").Value, "guid")
If UBound(arr, 1) > 0 Then
    For iArr = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        MsgBox Mid(arr(iArr), 3, InStr(arr(iArr), ",") - 3)
    Next
End If
```

---

edit after OP's comment

to face the "guids" vs "guid" occurrence you could first change all "guids" to "guid" with Replace() function

```
arr = Split(Replace(Range("A1").Value, "guids", "guid"), "guid")
```

Comment: Nice work around but what if I have some other columns with same name but just one character more like "guids" ? it will read 'guids' too with 'guid'... what to do in that case?

Comment: I’ll think it over. While you really could post a new question stating ALL your needs

Comment: As long as “guids” vs “guid” is the additional issue, you could first change all “guids” to “guid” with Replace() function and then go on with this solution