# VBA - Iterate through - Regex - Foreach Key

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342181/vba-regex-string-in-a-word).

How to iterate for each key like:

```
        For k = 1 To 40
            If allThings(k) <> "" Then
                Dim rsp As String, ptrn As String, i As Long, arr()
                rsp = [A1]
                ptrn = "" + allThings(k) + """:(\d+[^,])""" 'guid,name,ispool,...

                arr = GetMatches(rsp, ptrn)
                For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    MsgBox arr(i)
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As follows, just for the concatenating in new search word into the regex.

You might want to swop the regex line (depending on what characters can appear to something like `GetMatches(s, arr2(j) & """:(""?[A-Za-z0-9]+[^,])")`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test2()
    Dim rsp As String, i As Long, j As Long, arr2(), arr()
 
    arr2 = Array("guid", "name", "ispool")
    rsp = [A1]
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        arr = GetMatches(rsp, arr2(j) & """:(""?\w+[^,])")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print arr(i)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Public Function GetMatches(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object, s As String, arrMatches(), i As Long

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern

        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            ReDim arrMatches(0 To matches.Count - 1)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                arrMatches(i) = iMatch.submatches.item(0)
                i = i + 1
            Next iMatch
        Else
            ReDim arrMatches(0)
            arrMatches(0) = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
    GetMatches = arrMatches
End Function
```

---

**Regex** - Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/086t1M/1)

Example with `name`

```
name":("?\w+[^,])
/
gm
name": matches the characters name": literally (case sensitive)
```

1st Capturing Group `("?\w+[^,])`
`"?` matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
`?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Match a single character not present in the list below `[^,]`
`,` matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

---

**Results:**

[image]

---

If not using it as an UDF that it will be more efficient to pass the regex object into the function via the signature:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test2()
    Dim rsp As String, re As Object, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, arr2(), arr()
    
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    
    arr2 = Array("guid", "name", "ispool")
    rsp = [A1]
    
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            
        arr = GetMatches(rsp, arr2(j) & """:(""?\w+[^,])", re)
        
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print arr(i)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetMatches(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String, ByVal re As Object) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object, s As String, arrMatches(), i As Long

    With re
    
        .Pattern = sPattern

        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            ReDim arrMatches(0 To matches.Count - 1)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                arrMatches(i) = iMatch.submatches.Item(0)
                i = i + 1
            Next iMatch
        Else
            ReDim arrMatches(0)
            arrMatches(0) = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
    GetMatches = arrMatches
End Function
```